# adding controller in asp.net mvc 4web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mwxJ8.jpg)
This is the sample project on which i am doing.In Student_Page,i want to add more pages related Student,so what i have to do.
I am trying to add all the other controllers in one controller so as to give many sub link/button in Student_Page.

Comment: Step 1: Go read a tutorial on MVC and learn the very basics.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please, take a [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and observe what and how to [ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking). If you include code, please read about [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Thanks.